# "Friends of friends" category appears in chat on some computers only

Tags: facebook

There is a "Friends of friends" category in my chat window, which suggests I can initiate a chat session with non-friends. However, the feature only appears when I'm accessing Facebook from certain computers. I'm using Firefox 25 on all of my machines.

Could this be Facebook testing the upcoming "[host chat](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/27/facebook-chat-rooms)" feature?